# Overloading the subtraction operator for removing object

Tags: c#, overloading, operator-keyword

```
case Choices.ADD_PERSON:
                    Console.WriteLine("enter info for person to add.");
                    InfoForPerson();
                    PersonList Z = x + p;
                    break;

case Choices.REMOVE_PERSON:
                    Console.WriteLine("enter info for person to remove: ");
                    InfoForPerson();
                    Z = x - p;
                    break;
```

Above are two things that occur if their options are selected from the menu. For `Choices.ADD_PERSON` the result is as expected, and a person is added. However, I assumed + & - would function the exact same way, just inversely, but it hasn't occurred as such.

```
public static PersonList operator -(PersonList x, Person y)
    {
        PersonList temp = x;
        if (temp._Plist.Contains(y))
        {
            temp._Plist.Remove(y);
        }
        return temp; }
```

Above is my definition for the subtraction operator. Below is the code I was using to allow the user to choose the person to add/subtract.

```
public static void InfoForPerson()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        string phone = ValidPhone();
        string email = ValidEmail();
        p = new Person(name, phone, email);
```

It works fine for the addition, just not the subtraction. I watched p and it's holding the data fine, but it's just not matching the item already in the List.

Comment: Is overloading +/- in order to add/remove from a 'list' really a good idea?  It seems like a recipe for incredibly unintuitive code.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I agree with sapi.  Please don't do this.  Add a Remove method instead of trying to redefine other operators to do something different to what everyone thinks they will do.

Comment: I realize Remove would be simpler, but where does operator overloading have a use then if there's already an effective way to perform actions on user defined classes?

Comment: @user1993843 Useful for doing math operations on custom classes. For example, if you were to roll your own `Degrees` or `Radians` classes, it makes a lot of sense to use `+` or `-` with them. Or for example, subtracting two `DateTime` objects to obtain a `TimeSpan`. Using it on a `List` is generally non-conventional and you almost always never see it. (at least, I never have until today!)

Comment: Yesterday you asked this about the addition operator: many people told you this was an anti-pattern, or at least very non-idiomatic. Nothing changes when describing instead the subtract operator, and nothing has changed since yesterday.

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll give up on doing math on People. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Everyone else is right here. Do not make "cute" operators. The C++ use of `<<` is an anti-pattern; do not mimic it. The semantics of an addition should be *arithmetic addition*, and that's all. It is bad enough that it means string concatenation and delegate combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already noted by @sapi and @TheEvilPenguin, this type of operator overloading is frowned on for several very good reasons.  That doesn't answer your question however.

Without more information on where you're getting `p` from in the `Z = x - p` statement, I would suspect that your problem is that `p` isn't an element that exists in the list.

Bear in mind that `Contains` and `Remove` will only be valid for specific instances of an object in the list.

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> collection = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
collection.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 1));
if (collection.Contains(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 1))
{
    Console.WriteLine("This will NEVER happen.");
}
collection.Remove(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 1);
Console.WriteLine("{0}", collection.Count); // => 1
```

If you want to test for the existence of *any instances of a type with the same properties as the tested value* then `Contains` is not going to do it.

As another point, the `-` operator *should* not (some would say ***MUST*** not) modify the left-hand operand.  You should be returning a new list that contains the filtered items, because that's the syntactic operation of `A - B`.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever type of list (or collection) you are using for `_Plist` need to support matching `Person` as "value" (default if reference). You may either pass custom comparator to Contains function or implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on `Person` to compare all properties.

Note: as everyone said using +/- in non math related classes will lead to non-intuitive code. I.e. you already have strange behavior - if element is not there `-` will do nothing. This never happens for numbers: `whatever -2` never equals `whatever`.